# How to show a caret-C in canceled command line in zsh, like bash does?

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh

When I'm in the middle of entering a line to my shell of choice, and change my mind, I can quickly throw `C-c` and start afresh. Under `bash` it looks like this:

```
user@machine:~$ rm everything^C
user@machine:~$
```

But on `zsh`, which I really prefer overall, shows nothing:

```
(~) rm -rf /
(~)
```

Yeah, you may see why I would like to see that caret-C or similar message over the line so that I don't confuse which line have actually been executed and are in history for that matter.

This small issue is largely ungoogleable.

Comment: Did you try `stty echoctl` ?

Comment: @wurtel: that has effect on bash but not on zsh.

Comment: You could use the `kill-whole-line` widget - by default bound to `^U` (`C-u`) - instead of `^C`. This just removes everything from the current line and nothing confusing would remain.

Comment: @Adaephon: well, that's the current workout whenever I use that. I think there should be a way to make that character show. Or other message, by some means.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a trap for *SIGINT* (triggered by `CTRL-C`), which will print `^C` (or any other text you would like):

```
TRAPINT() {
  print -n "^C"
  return $(( 128 + $1 ))
}
```

This example is taken from `man zshmisc`. The return command has the following background:

> Programs terminated by uncaught signals typically return the status 128 plus the signal number.  Hence the [above code] causes the handler for SIGINT to print a message, then mimic the usual effect of the signal.